# Python 3 ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Tags: python-3.x

My dataset which is Russian text looks like this:

[image]

the parsing code fragment looks like this:

```
# mydata = ET.dump(sentences_el)
mydata = ET.tostring(sentences_el)
with open(fn, "wb", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>')
    f.write(mydata)
    f.close()
```

And I am having following error:
[image]

Could someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Do not use binary mode if you want to use encoding

Comment: try after removing encoding='utf-8'

Answer (score 2):

If you are using binary mode then encoding should not be needed

try removing `encoding='utf-8'`